# Appending data from multiple excel files into a single excel file without overwriting using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

Here is my current code below.

I have a specific range of cells (from a specific sheet) that I am pulling out of multiple (~30) excel files. I am trying to pull this information out of all these files to compile into a single new file appending to that file each time. I'm going to manually clean up the destination file for the time being as I will improve this script going forward.

What I currently have works fine for a single sheet but I overwrite my destination every time I add a new file to the read in list.

I've tried adding the `mode = 'a'` and a couple different ways to concat at the end of my function.

```
import pandas as pd

def excel_loader(fname, sheet_name, new_file):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(fname)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name, nrows = 20)
    print(df1[1:15])
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_file)
    df1.insert(51, 'Original File', fname)
    df1.to_excel(new_file)

names = ['sheet1.xlsx', 'sheet2.xlsx']
destination = 'destination.xlsx'

for name in names:
    excel_loader(name, 'specific_sheet_name', destination)
```

Thanks for any help in advance can't seem to find an answer to this exact situation on here. Cheers.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't modify excel files using pandas, you need another library like `xlwings`, best thing to do is to load the excel contents into a dataframe and do only one write

Comment: I had thought modifying Excel files was a fairly standard use for pandas. I am able to add data into a new column currently with this line: `df1.insert(51, 'Original File', fname)` which just adds a column with the header of 'Original File' and adds the origin file name as for the rest of the rows. I will check out `xlwings` though!

Comment: Pandas stands for Panel Data, so being able to read and write excel files is just what you would expect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to loop through the files and read the data into a list, then concatenate the individual dataframes, then write the new dataframe. This assumes the data being pulled is the same size/shape and the sheet name is the same. If sheet name is changing, look into zip() function to send filename/sheetname tuple.

This should get you started:

```
names = ['sheet1.xlsx', 'sheet2.xlsx']
destination = 'destination.xlsx'

#read all files first
df_hold_list = []
for name in names:
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(name)
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name, nrows = 20)
    df_hold_list.append(df)

#concatenate dfs 
df1 = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=1) # axis is 1 or 0 depending on how you want to cancatenate (horizontal vs vertical)

#write new file - may have to correct this piece - not sure what functions these are
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(destination)
df1.to_excel(destination)
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that with this I was able to get exactly the result that I was looking for. Really appreciate the help on this one. Cheers friend!